# Setting "allow pages to choose their own fonts" on a per-domain basis in Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, firefox-extensions

Normally I use Firefox with the option "allow pages to choose their own fonts" UNselected, but now and again there's a site I'd like to view using their fonts instead of mine... Is it possible to set this option on a per-domain basis? A plugin maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two Firefox add-ons that are open-source and can be used to solve the
problem in another way than setting "Allow pages to choose their own fonts":

- [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)
- [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) (a fork of Stylish)

Both add-ons allow to override the CSS styles of websites, and both support
[@-moz-document rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@document),
which allow regex specifications for overridden websites, including negative look-ahead.

These examples come from the article
[Applying styles to specific sites](https://github.com/stylish-userstyles/stylish/wiki/Applying-styles-to-specific-sites):

> An example of matching all sites with a certain exception:
>
> ```
> @-moz-document regexp('(?!http://www\\.example\\.com).*') {
>   /*
>       the code in here applies to all URLs except those that start with 
>       http://www.example.com
>   */
> }
> ```
>
> An example of matching all except a specific section of a site:
>
> ```
> @-moz-document regexp('http://www\\.example\\.com/(?!members).*') {
>   /*
>       the code in here applies to all URLs on http://www.example.com, except
>       those under http://www.example.com/members
>   */
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I've found a bug in the Bugzilla of Mozilla. If you still interested in this problem, you can add a comment with your requests.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=568794

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and found this plug-in:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/document-font-toggle/?src=api

It allows to toggle between choosing your own fonts and use the ones set by the site.  It also has pre-sets for "always allow"  and "always deny" by domain so you don't have to manually toggle.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: How should this be implemented on a per domain level? Looking at the source code it does not look like that there is this functionality. The issue is that `browser.display.use_document_fonts` is a global setting for all sites.

Comment: The addon has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be what you're looking for: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/

Comment: Sadly here http://userstyles.org/help/coding it says that "there is no way to select everything except a certain site", so Stylish doesn't fit with my scenario :/